# DNN 9.0.2 - Create/Add Roles after authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, dotnetnuke

I have a custom Authentication Module that retrieves token from Azure AD B2C. So i had to overriding OAuthClientBase to send Policy to Azure AD B2C for authentication. I am able to successfully authenticate and receive tokens that includes custom Roles. To retrieve the token, I am overriding OAuthClientBase -> GetCurrentUser method. After receiving the tokens, DNN Core library creates user and roles if not exists in the DNN Database. But instead, I would like to override the creation by sending a flag (IsApproved=true) while creating the user and add additional roles that are being sent by the AD B2C Token. How can this functionality be achieved? Can this be achieved by extending OAuthClientBase class or any other class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show us what have you tried so far , so that it would be more easier to figure out your problem exactly for the contributor. Thank you.

Comment: i am facing a challenge in adding custom user roles and make the new user as authorized.
In the "GetToken" method that gets overriding from OAuthClientBase, I am setting the custom Roles as shown below:
JwtSecurityToken.Payload.AddClaims( new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "custom role 1") } );

But somehow this claim is not being used while creating user roles. Also i am unable to set the user default authorized as true. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure AD B2C and DNN Platform integration, check the open source module at https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider. The module **supports B2C/DNN role synchronization** and will probably solve your needs.